# Remove WooCommerce thumbnail links

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using jquery script to display product thumbnail images in main product image box.

```
jQuery(document).on('mousedown','.thumbnails .zoom', function(){
      var photo_fullsize =  jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('-100x100','');
      jQuery('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('src', photo_fullsize);
      return false;
    });
```

The problem is that if i click on the thumbnail image, it opens up in main product image box, but also in lightbox. How could I remove lightbox from thumbnail links? I don't want any link at all. I only want lightbox in main product image box.

I found the following code from product-thumbnails.php:

```
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="%s" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_class, $image_title, $image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );
```

But how to change that so it only displays the image and not link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by removing all of the `<a href="">` tag, except the last `%s` and removing `$image_link, $image_class, $image_title,`. The line of code would change **from**:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="%s" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_class, $image_title, $image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );
```

**to**

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '%s', $image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );
```

EDIT:
To remove the light box you can do one of the following:

**change**

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="%s" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_class, $image_title, $image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );
```

**to**

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s"> %s</a>', $image_link, $image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );
```

**OR**

Go to your dashboard -> Woocommerce -> Settings -> General -> Scripts (down at the bottom of the page) and untick the "Enable Lightbox" option, BUT turning off that option will turn off the lightbox for all images in woocommerce.

Doing either of the above will cause the image to open in a new tab.

Comment: this is buggy. The images are now without link, but a) that jquery script does not work anymore and b) all images are bigger, take hell of a lot room and all images are blurry.  Maybe there's a way to "turn off" lightroom from thumbnails somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I had a heck of a time finding an answer as to how to remove the LINKS but not break the ability to insert the picture into the main image area, that was in line with woocommerce's current set up.

To remove the links, first ensure you've copied product-thumbnails.php over to your own theme to prevent overwriting on update.

Second, in that file find this, on line 53

```
echo apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html',
            sprintf(
                '<a href="%s" class="%s" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>',
                esc_url( $props['url'] ),
                esc_attr( $image_class ),
                esc_attr( $props['caption'] ),
                wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_thumbnail' ), 0, $props )
            ),
            $attachment_id,
            $post->ID,
            esc_attr( $image_class )
```

In that section of code, remove href="%s" and then remove esc_url( $props['url'] ), for:

```
            echo apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html',
            sprintf(
                '<a class="%s" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>',
                esc_attr( $image_class ),
                esc_attr( $props['caption'] ),
                wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_thumbnail' ), 0, $props )
            ),
            $attachment_id,
            $post->ID,
            esc_attr( $image_class )
```

Job done. Using another bit of code I was able to maintain the hover over the thumbs, still putting them in the main image area without them being clickable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove just the lightbox you can remove the `data-rel` attribute, else if you don't want any link in the thumbnail you can change your php page to this:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '%s', $image_title, $image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );
```

the only problem is if you use the a class with CSS code, in this case I think you should empty the href value.

Comment: I tried both of them already, and tried them again. These solutions do not work :( The change u suggested changes the thumbnails images to image caption texts.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, `echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '%s',$image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );`
This one should work!

Comment: this is buggy. The images are now without link, but a) that jquery script does not work anymore and b) all images are bigger, take hell of a lot room and all images are blurry.  Maybe there's a way to "turn off" lightroom from thumbnails?